# How to add Compass syntax support to Jetbrains PhpStorm?

Tags: css, compass-sass, phpstorm

I'm using JetBrains PhpStorm, which is probably the most epic IDE I've ever used.

The question is simple. How do I add Compass syntax support to it? I've got it installed, it renders and works, but PhpStorm still complains about undefined imports and mixins.

How can I resolve this? Can Compass be included as an external library?

---

**Edit**: I'd just like to note that **[this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-8299)** is for the RubyMine IDE (also by JetBrains), it's not for PhpStorm/WebStorm.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-8299 I guess

Comment: @LazyOne: Don't think so, it's listed under the Ruby project, not under the WebStorm/PhpStorm one.

Comment: If that is the only reason -- then you are wrong, I'm afraid. Any issue for JavaScript or Deployment (S/FTP/S) or HTML or Spell Checker etc in RubyMine will be transferred to PhpStorm project as it is home for such issues. At the same time Ruby project is home for SASS/SCSS/LESS/HAML issues. You have to keep in mind that Compass is built on top of SASS, and SASS/SCSS support in PhpStorm is done via plugin (which is true for almost all functionality). Therefore it is the correct issue to look after.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's explanation of Martin's answer. 
Symlink to compass gem directory in your sass folder works great.

Instruction(Windows)

1. open cmd with admin privileges
2. change path to your project sass folder, for example `cd projectname\sass`
3. run `mklink /d compass $GEM_LOCATION\frameworks\compass\stylesheets\compass`, as for me $GEM_LOCATION = `C:\dev\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\compass-0.12.2`

Thats all, now PhpStorm will not highlight compass mixins as errors, and will add them in autocomplete suggestions.

**Warning**: If you want to delete created symlink DON'T use delete, it will remove source directory.
open cmd with admin privileges, `cd $yourProjectSassPath`, and run `rmdir compass`

Comment: Thank you. It didn't work for me, CMD says the symlink has been created, but I don't see any new files there when opened with explorer, and PhpStorm still doesn't recognize them.

Comment: After removing the slash behind `compass`, it worked. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Added compass and aurora stylesheet dirs as symlniks, didn't do it

Comment: I should also note that in PHPStorm, NO compass mixins, variables, etc, are identified by the IDE, no matter where they reside in the project.

Comment: still gets: `error main.scss (Line 2: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.` What must the import statement be? `@import 'compass';`?

Comment: main.scss should be in same folder where you have symlink. yes, if you use all features of compass.  I use only `@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass/css3/user-interface";
@import "compass/utilities";`

Comment: Are there any instructions for Mac?

Comment: NOTE about Warning above: if you delete symlink from PHPStorm it recognizes the symlink and prompts to remove it (not the source data)

Answer (score 9):

As the above user mentioned it also works to add the path to the Compass stylesheets as a resource directory in your project.

For example, my compass stylesheets are located at:
`C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets`

1. Go to Settings > Project settings > Directories.
2. Add a content root
3. Add the compass stylesheets directory
4. Click 'Resource Root' (the blue icon)

When you apply you will see that PhpStorm finds the compass stylesheets without any problems. You can even ctrl+click (windows) on them to open them directly.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 It works, but in my case: 3. add ".../frameworks/compass" as content root 4.Select 'stylesheets' folder in the tree view. 5. Click 'resource root' (the blue icon)

Comment: Definitely the best solution. Didn't work for me just adding the `stylesheets` directory in Ruby 2.0.3 on Linux though, I had to include the parent `compass-core-1.0.3` directory.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by placing a symlink of the `compass`-directory (from `$GEM_LOCATION/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass`) into the folder where my stylesheet lives. It's more of a workaround but it makes me and the phpstorm-inspections/-autocompletion happy.

Comment: What's a symlink? Note I'm running Windows.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: It didn't work for me, could you elaborate more on the process?

Comment: when you install compass, all of it's .scss-files are installed to some location, possibly depending on where your ruby-installation lives (you can use the command `gem environment` to find out the path, look for `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`, should be something like `.../Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1`). Within this directory you'll find the compass-gem, which in turn contains the directory mentioned above.

Comment: As for the symlinks, you can try to copy the files instead, but you should make sure to exclude them from your projects version-control…

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to add the directory in the Directories settings: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/directories.html

In the example above, add a new content root of C:\dev\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\compass-0.12.2.

Comment: Adding the proper folder is not as good as the symlink solution because you cannot control scope of the compass source files very well.  With symlinks you know exactly what you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

This is more easily fixed by using a better source for the executable.

From: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9139

In Windows, use an executable path like:

```
C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\compass-0.12.2\bin\compass
```

While on the Mac use something like:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass
```