# How to use compass in phpstorm?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, phpstorm

I'm aware of this question:
[How to add Compass syntax support to Jetbrains PhpStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213631/how-to-add-compass-syntax-support-to-jetbrains-phpstorm#) but it doesn't help.

I just opted for copying the files over, much easier in my project. But phpstorm still complains about compass. Without compass it compiles scss using ruby 1.9.3 without problems. Is my set up correct?

[image]

**EDIT**:

This is for PhpStorm 6-

[Compass is supported](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew) in PhpStorm 7+

Comment: Check comments in corresponding ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-5802#comment=27-471454

Comment: PHPStorm 7 just added support for Compass http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First of all, the question that you had linked is about enabling support for Compass-style imports, and it is a workaround that does not work for every project.

Your question is about a different thing: *compiling Compass projects*.

Both issues will be addressed in the 7th version of PHPStorm, which is not going to be released soon: the 6th version has just been released. For now, there's a number of workarounds.

### Compiling Compass projects with PHPStorm manually

1. Go to the **External tools** section of PHPStorm IDE Settings.
2. Create a **new** external tool. Name it "Compass compile manual" or similarly.
3. Set the **Program** to point at your Compass binary. On Windows it's like `C:\Ruby193\bin\compass.bat`, on Linux and Mac it can be simply `compass`. But if you're using RVM, then the *Program* should be `bash`.
4. The **Parameters** field should be `compile` for all OSes, unless you're using RVM. For RVM the **Parameters** should be set to `–login -c "compass compile"`.
5. The **Working directory** field should be set to `$ProjectFileDir$`.

Manual compilation can be launched from the **Tools** menu. You can also assign a hotkey to run it quicker. Make sure that hotkey does not collide with an existing one.

### Making PHPStorm compile your project whenever you save changes

1. Make sure you have the very latest Early Access Preview version of PHPStorm. You can download it from [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program).
2. Make sure you have the **File Watchers** plugin installed. Go to the **Plugins** section of PHPStorm IDE Settings, look for **File Watchers**. If it's not on the list, install it via 
   **Browse repositories** and restart PHPStorm.
3. Open your project in PHPStorm if you haven't done it already.
4. Go to the **File Watchers** section of PHPStorm Project Settings.
5. Create a **new** File Watcher. Use a **custom** template. Name your watcher "Compass compile on save" or similarly.
6. Set the **File type** to either SCSS or SASS, depending which one you use in your project.
7. Leave the **Scope** as "Project files"
8. Set the **Program** to point at your Compass binary. On Windows it's like `C:\Ruby193\bin\compass.bat`, on Linux and Mac it can be simply `compass`. But if you're using RVM, then the *Program* should be `bash`.
9. The **Arguments** field should be `compile` for all OSes, unless you're using RVM. For RVM the **Arguments** should be set to `–login -c "compass compile"`. **UPD:** @ezekiel-victor suggests this to be: `–login -c "compile --sass-dir=$ProjectFileDir$ --css-dir=$ProjectFileDir$"`.
10. The **Working directory** field should be set to `$ProjectFileDir$`.
11. Disable `Check for syntax errors`.
12. Leave the rest blank and save.

Now whenever you save changes to any of your SCSS or SASS files, PHPStorm will tell Compass to compile the project.

**UPD** If you're using Bundler (there's `Gemfile` in your project and you do `bundle install` to fetch dependencies), you shoud use `bundle exec compass compile` instead of `compass compile`. This means that you have to use the `bundle` executable (`bundle.bat` on Windows) instead of `compass` (`compass.bat`) and adjust the `Arguments` field accordingly.

### Running `compass watch` manually in OS console (recommended)

The problem with running `compass compile` is that it's slow as it recompiles the whole project every time it is executed.

Instead, you can run a `compass watch` command manually in the project folder using your OS console. Compass Watch will constantly monitor your project for changes. When changes are noticed, it will recompile only the modified part, which is much faster.

Compass Watch is smart enough not to monitor every file in your project. It only monitors non-partial files (e. g. `screen.scss`) and partials (e. g. `_layout.scss`) that are imported by any non-partial file or by imported partials recursively.

If you work with your project over a network filesystem (e. g. when using a virtual machine or a development server to run your code), compilation and tracking changes become too slow. So the best option when using remote/virtual machine is to run `compass watch` on that machine so that it tracks changes locally and not via a network file system.

### Reanimating Compass

Compass caches it's own work to make compilation faster. Sometimes the cache becomes inconsistent with project contents. This results in Compass reporting all kinds of weird errors and refusing to compile your project.

Once you feel that Compass reports an error that is not true, execute `compass clean` and recompile your project. Cleaning will purge Compass cache and complied files, so that it starts from scratch.

You can run `compass clean` manually in console or add it as a PHPStorm External Tool.

Comment: I couldn't get this work as written. I don't have rvm (assuming it means Ruby Version Manager), but I do have rbenv on my OS X machine. In step 8, I set Program to bash. In step 9, I set Arguments to compass compile and the path to my project. It works with these settings. I see that version 7 of PHPStorm was just announced. I look forward to GA.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but please consider updating your answer. I had to make the following changes to get the File Watcher to work in PHPStorm: 1) Change arguments to make dirs explicit: "compile --sass-dir=$ProjectFileDir$ --css-dir=$ProjectFileDir$", 2) blank out "Output paths".

Comment: @EzekielVictor, i've never been using this, so thank you for keeping an eye on it. I've added your #1 suggestion to the answer. I didn't add #2 because there's already "leave other fields blank" recommendation. I also added a paragraph on using Bundler.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone - on Snow Leopard, compass is installed in the following directory (obviously version numbers in the path depend on the installed version):

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass
```

So for the **Program:** option you can select it there.

Comment: You're right. If you don't specify this directory, PhpStorm can't find the compass library to include it in your project. This problem is described here : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9139

Answer (score 0):

Please check comments in corresponding ticket (Support for Compass) on JetBrains issue tracker: few comments have instructions on how to make it work even in current versions of the IDE:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-5802#comment=27-471454

Answer (score 0):

I am using PhpStorm 2017.1.4

Setting the Ruby path variable and enabling compass in PhpStorm did not work out for me.

I could not use compass from the project directory ("Failed to run Compass") because the terminal could not resolve the command compass with the executable from the Ruby instal dir.

Thus, I permanently set a windows (using win10) environment variable following this [explanation](http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch01-01.html).

Quick explanation:

- Assuming you have already installed ruby and compass.
- Go to: `Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables...`
- Add `C:\Ruby22\bin` to your `PATH` variable
- Restart PhpStorm

Further advice:

If you imported your Project from a different system it might help if you delete your `config.rb` filed and run `compass init` from your project root.