# Can't Find Compass Imports after Compass Install

Tags: sass, compass-sass, phpstorm

I'm updating a PHP project using PHPStorm. I first started using SCSS by turning on the PHPStorm watch for the file type. It works fine. I then wanted to incorporate Compass. I successfully installed it and ran "Compass create --bare" in my project directory. Now when I include @import "compass/typography/vertical_rhythm", it can't find it. It's not surprising as there is no compass subdirectory. How do I install the required components? Didn't see any Compass option that seemed appropriate. I used the bare option because thats what's the Compass site gave me for an existing project.

Once I get it installed, do I need the Compass watch given I already have a file watcher running for SCSS files? The description of it indicates it does the same thing.

Running OS X 10.8.4

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question again. I should have plugged away a little longer. I'll leave this in case someone has the same problem.

The @import "compass/typography/vertical_rhythm is resolved by the the Compass compiler. Just running a vanilla SASS compiler isn't going to do it. At this point I make this happen by running compass compile on a bash command line. I haven't been been able to get the PHPStorm watcher to work correctly. A new version of PHPStorm was announced yesterday (5 Sep 2013) with additional support for Compass.

**Update**

There's another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806938/how-to-use-compass-in-phpstorm) asking how to get compass compile to work with PHPStorm. It didn't work as written for me. I made a comment there on the changes I made to get it to do so.