# Why is Sass/Compass inserting strange compact() functions into my code, breaking it?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I've written a stylesheet with Sass/Compass with these mixins:

```css
$buttonbackground: #50bfec
$darkerbackground: darken($buttonbackground, 30%)
$lighterbackground: lighten($buttonbackground, 20%)    

+background-image(linear-gradient(#6b8e23, white))
+single-text-shadow    
+box-shadow($lighterbackground 0 0 25px, $darkerbackground 0 0 3px 1px inset)

// all copied from examples
```

Instead of producing code on the lines of this (from the manual)

```css
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4) 0 0 25px, rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.2) 0 0 3px 1px inset;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4) 0 0 25px, rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.2) 0 0 3px 1px inset;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4) 0 0 25px, rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.2) 0 0 3px 1px inset
```

it produces stuff like this

```css
-webkit-box-shadow: compact(#ace1f6 0 0 25px, #106d93 0 0 3px 1px inset, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
-moz-box-shadow: compact(#ace1f6 0 0 25px, #106d93 0 0 3px 1px inset, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
box-shadow: compact(#ace1f6 0 0 25px, #106d93 0 0 3px 1px inset, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
```

which doesn't work. Code with these strange compact functions (which don't appear to be in Sass or the CSS3 spec) and excessive `false`s appear for my `+linear-gradient` and `+single-text-shadow` mixins. (I don't use SCSS)

What is happening and how can I make it output correct and working code? FYI I use a workaround outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13659959/2604868) to make Compass work in WebStorm (my IDE), and I use a Mac.

Comment: `compact()` is a Compass function written in Ruby and is invoked by many of the css3 functions (see [the box-shadow source](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/css3/_box-shadow.scss)).  An undefined function will be written as is in the compiled CSS, which is what's happening here.

Comment: @cimmanon OK. So how can I make it output working code?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you any farther than this, I use Compass via command line.  You'll have to find a way to get WebStorm to find the missing function(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that because of `compact()` being a Ruby method I needed to use the `compass` command (not `sass`).